# Trying to get CoinGecko API and user input to calculate and then output

Tags: javascript, coingecko

Ive been trying to make this work for a while but cant seem to get my newbie head around this. I can console.log the coin, but cant seem to get it to multiply with "btcnumber' input and then update .innerText

```js
const api_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Cbinancecoin%2Ccardano%2Csolana%2Cterra-luna&vs_currencies=usd";
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.bitcoin.usd);
}
getData();


function coinValue() {
    let bitcoin = parseInt(document.getElementById("btcnumber") * (data.bitcoin.usd));
    document.getElementById("c-v").innerText = bitcoin.toFixed(8);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let submit = document.getElementById("calculateButton");
    calculateButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        coinValue()
    })

})
```

```html
<input id="btcnumber" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number Purchased">
                                    
<button id="calculateButton" onclick=coinValue()>Calculate</button>

<h4>CURRENT VALUE <span id="c-v"></span></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in the `coinValue()` function the `data` variable does not exists. Make that a global variable by placing it out of the function.

Also inside `coinValue()` function you have to add `.value` at the end of your multiplication to get the actual value of the input.

```js
let data;

const api_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Cbinancecoin%2Ccardano%2Csolana%2Cterra-luna&vs_currencies=usd";
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.bitcoin.usd);
}
getData();


function coinValue() {
    let bitcoin = parseInt(document.getElementById("btcnumber").value * (data.bitcoin.usd));
    document.getElementById("c-v").innerText = bitcoin.toFixed(8);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let submit = document.getElementById("calculateButton");
    calculateButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        coinValue()
    })

})
```

```html
<input id="btcnumber" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number Purchased">
                                    
<button id="calculateButton" onclick=coinValue()>Calculate</button>

<h4>CURRENT VALUE <span id="c-v"></span></h4>
```